# Render component in vue based on condition

Tags: vue.js

I have been trying to render some components in the navbar based on the email/account that is currently signing in. Currently there is a function "getUser()" that will get the user's email. So in the navbar there are: Home, Procurement Site, Monitoring, Admin and Log out. I am putting a condition only for admin@gmail.com then the "Admin" section in the navbar can be visible. I have tried ensuring that the function works and returning the email address and also using

```
<template v-if="this.email == 'admin@gmail.com'">
     <li class="nav-item">
         <router-link to= "/Admin"> Admin </router-link>
     </li>
</template>
```

The code above does work by hiding the admin section in the navbar, but it doesn't work even if I login by the admin@gmail.com account. Please help. Thank you

Full code for navbar:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to= "/Procurement"> Home </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to= "/ProcurementSite"> Procurement Sites </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to= "/Monitoring"> Monitoring </router-link>
          </li>
            <template v-if="this.email == 'admin@gmail.com'">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to= "/Admin"> Admin </router-link>
                </li>
            </template>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link to="/" v-on:click="logOut()"> Log Out </router-link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
<script>
    import $backend from './../backend'
    
    export default {
      name: 'nav',
      data () {
          return {
            email: ''
          }
          
      },
      methods: {
        getUser () {
            console.log("in get user in monitor vue")
            $backend.getUser()
            .then(responseData => {   
            this.email = responseData.result
            console.log(this.email)
            }).catch(error => {
            this.error = error.message
            })
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of `this.email` when you `console.log` it? Also, where do you call the `getUser` method?

Comment: I tried to print somewhere in the page by {{ this.email }} and get admin@gmail.com. Isn't it by using "this.email" will get the value?

Comment: But I did put the getUser in the section beforeMount

Comment: can you edit your question and share more code( like where do you invoke the getUser method) or a link to a live demo on codesandbox if you can

Comment: Dude remove ''this'' keyword from template

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to help you.

Check out the code in action here: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

`"Yes, you are the admin"` will only show if the email is `admin@gmail.com`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    E-mail:
    <span>
      {{email}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Are you admin? <span v-show="email == 'admin@gmail.com'">Yes, you are the admin</span>
  </div>
  <input v-model="email" >
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      email: "admin@gmail.com"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```